# Trying to convert function-based countdown clock program to JS class format

Tags: javascript, class, oop

What I did earlier. This is the countdown code I have wrote using functions. The purpose is to make a countdown clock using Vanilla JS.

```
const refs = {
  day: document.querySelector("span[data-value='days']"),
  hour: document.querySelector("span[data-value='hours']"),
  min: document.querySelector("span[data-value='mins']"),
  sec: document.querySelector("span[data-value='secs']"),
};

const targetDate = new Date("Jul 17, 2021");

function updateClockface(time) {
  const days = pad(Math.floor(time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
  const hours = pad(
    Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))
  );
  const mins = pad(Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)));
  const secs = pad(Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60)) / 1000));

  refs.day.textContent = `${days}`;
  refs.hour.textContent = `${hours}`;
  refs.min.textContent = `${mins}`;
  refs.sec.textContent = `${secs}`;
}

function pad(value) {
  return String(value).padStart(2, "0");
}

let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  const startTime = Date.now();
  let diff = targetDate - startTime;
  updateClockface(diff);
}, refs.sec);
```

But, right now, I am trying to rewrite it using js-classes. Attaching what I've tried, even though I know I did a lot of mistakes in it. Total newbie in classes.

```
const refs = {
  day: document.querySelector("span[data-value='days']"),
  hour: document.querySelector("span[data-value='hours']"),
  min: document.querySelector("span[data-value='mins']"),
  sec: document.querySelector("span[data-value='secs']"),
};

class Countdown {
  constructor(selector, targetDate) {
    this.$el = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.targetDate = targetDate;
  }
  getClockItems(time) {
    const days = pad(Math.floor(time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
    const hours = pad(
      Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))
    );
    const mins = pad(Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)));
    const secs = pad(Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60)) / 1000));

    updateClock = () => {
      refs.day.textContent = `${days}`;
      refs.hour.textContent = `${hours}`;
      refs.min.textContent = `${mins}`;
      refs.sec.textContent = `${secs}`;
    };
  }

  pad(value) {
    return String(value).padStart(2, "0");
  }
  loadingTimer = setInterval(() => {
    const startTime = Date.now();
    let diff = targetDate - startTime;
    updateClockface(diff);
  }, refs.sec);
}

new CountdownTimer({
  selector: "#timer-1",
  targetDate: new Date("Jul 17, 2021"),
});
```

Attaching HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="timer" id="timer-1">
      <div class="field">
        <span class="value" data-value="days">00</span>
        <span class="label">Days</span>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <span class="value" data-value="hours">00</span>
        <span class="label">Hours</span>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <span class="value" data-value="mins">00</span>
        <span class="label">Minutes</span>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <span class="value" data-value="secs">00</span>
        <span class="label">Seconds</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are rewriting it that way?  Just as an exercise?

Comment: @user120242 yeah, I am just trying to find better understanding in classes. Before that I did only simple examples, this one is a little bit beyond...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the code, so that it runs.  Mostly just a lot of issues with not using this for variables attached to the class, and a few other problems.  But it seems like you're still in the middle of getting the hang of using classes.

I'm not sure why you are trying to return a function updateClock, but that looks like a pattern you would use if you weren't trying to wrap it in a class.  You tried to pass an object to the constructor, but it's currently set up to take two parameters.

If you are looking for tips on how to "properly" make use of class syntax to clean up this code, I would recommend you go to the [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

```js
const refs = {
  day: document.querySelector("span[data-value='days']"),
  hour: document.querySelector("span[data-value='hours']"),
  min: document.querySelector("span[data-value='mins']"),
  sec: document.querySelector("span[data-value='secs']"),
};

class Countdown {
  constructor(selector, targetDate) {
    this.$el = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.targetDate = targetDate;
  }
  updateClockItems(time) {
    const pad = this.pad;
    
    const days = pad(Math.floor(time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
    const hours = pad(
      Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))
    );
    const mins = pad(Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)));
    const secs = pad(Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60)) / 1000));

      refs.day.textContent = `${days}`;
      refs.hour.textContent = `${hours}`;
      refs.min.textContent = `${mins}`;
      refs.sec.textContent = `${secs}`;

  }

  pad(value) {
    return String(value).padStart(2, "0");
  }
  loadingTimer = setInterval(() => {
    const startTime = Date.now();
    let diff = this.targetDate - startTime;
    this.updateClockItems(diff);
  }, refs.sec);
}

new Countdown(...Object.values({
  selector: "#timer-1",
  targetDate: new Date("Jul 17, 2021"),
}));
```

```html
Attaching HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>11th HW</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="timer" id="timer-1">
      <div class="field">
        <span class="value" data-value="days">00</span>
        <span class="label">Days</span>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <span class="value" data-value="hours">00</span>
        <span class="label">Hours</span>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <span class="value" data-value="mins">00</span>
        <span class="label">Minutes</span>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <span class="value" data-value="secs">00</span>
        <span class="label">Seconds</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir, thank you so much! Could you please recommend me how can I get better understanding of "this" method in classes? Don't understand how it works yet

Comment: And could you please also explain how does spread work right here ---new Countdown(...Object.values({
  selector: "#timer-1",
  targetDate: new Date("Jul 17, 2021"),
}));

?I mean do we need it there

Comment: Google's results on "JavaScript this" are already pretty good I think. Also "JavaScript context vs scope".   `this` can be mostly seen as a reference to "myself", so for example each new class instance will have its own set of variables in `this`.  In JavaScript this is in most normal cases just the object before the dot.  Also look at "Function.prototype.bind"

Comment: [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) converts `{ x: 1, y: 2 }` to `[1,2]`.  Then I "spread" the values `[1,2]` as function arguments, which turns into `func(1,2)`

Comment: Thank you so much clarification, will be working on getting 'this' done.

Comment: My biggest problem right now is that I just don't need to know where should i put 'this', for example - why we need it 'const pad = this.pad?' and so on @user120242

Comment: Note: it's an ugly way to do it.  It was just the shortest convenient fix.  pad doesn't exist in the current scope.  It's in the context, and as member of the Countdown class.  So it only exists as this.pad or Countdown.prototype.pad.  Countdown.pad = ... would have been a slightly better way, but still not very good.  FYI pad function is a poor fit for the class, and you're better off just having it as a utility function that the class uses, because it doesn't benefit from encapsulation in Countdown (neither semantically)

Comment: You may also want to look at prototypal inheritance.  For the most part (not entirely), class syntax is just sugar over prototypal inheritance

Comment: This question should have been closed rather than answered. All you've done is fix all of the code and submit it as an "answer". SO is a place to teach and advise, not just rewrite code for people. Then when asked about certain things in the answer, you point to Google...

Comment: I gave my opinion, there's no need for a response like that...